# Center Excel Sheet regardless of Monitor Size

Tags: screen, center

I want to center an Excel Spreadsheet on any Size monitor with the Columns A thru V showing and Rows 1 thru 37 showing - So basically I need to be able to determine the size (width/height) of the monitor that the spreadsheet is running on and then adjust the spreadsheet to be as large as possible without overflowing the screen size.

Do any of you have VBA code that will accomplish this?

Thanks in advance -

Have looked at a couple of examples on Stack Overflow but not seeing exactly what I need